# For Loop Not Accepting ATTRIB command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having a bit of a problem. `FOR` loop is working with `ECHO` command but not with `ATTRIB`.

`for %G IN (*) DO ECHO %G`

This is returnig all the files in dir, but:

`for %G IN (*) DO ATTRIB %G`

is returning `Parameter format not correct -`.

Why is this happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file names contain spaces, which means you have to quote the argument to `attrib`:

```
for %G in (*) do attrib "%G"
```

Comment: Thanks, overtime is killing me xD